# 406 'Not Acceptable' Error from Basecamp API

Tags: node.js, axios, basecamp

I'm getting a 406 'Not Acceptable' error from the Basecamp API when using pagination. I'm using Axios in a Node.js script.

Here's an example URL:
`https://3.basecampapi.com/xxxxxxxxx/buckets/xxxxxxxxx/todosets/xxxxxxxxx/todolists.json?page=2`

I have tried many different Accept headers, including 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', '*/*', 'application/json', 'text/javascript'.

I only get the error when adding the 'page' parameter, so I can get page 1 fine.
I get no error when making the call from Postman. I've copied Postman's headers exactly and it still will not work.

Comment: What version of Axios are you using?

Comment: @Phil This solved it. I was using version 1.0.0. I updated to 1.1.2 and the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by updating Axios from version 1.0.0 to version 1.1.2.
Thanks to @Phil for the suggestion.